# No Apply button on Display settings Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

This seems to be an old topic that has not found an answer; maybe I'll have better luck.  I'm trying to change the display settings on my two-monitor configuration (Macbook Pro and ViewSonic external monitor).  The "Apply" button is missing on the Display settings screen.  What must I do to get it back?

Answer (score 0):

The "apply" button was not present after I changed an external monitor orientation. I discovered by chance that dragging the screen icon a tiny bit made the apply button magically appear.